# DX Scratch Org: Session expired or invalid on using JWT and jsforce

Tags: javascript, jsforce, salesforcedx, jwt, scratch-org

I have been testing FX and scratch orgs with jsforce and I based my first tests with this example. https://jsforce.github.io/blog/posts/20170629-salesforce-dx-with-jsforce.html
With the recommendation on the page, I tried using the JWT flow, but I am encountering auth issue with the created org. I just can't connect to it.
I have followed https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_connected_app.htm.

Am I missing something or there is an issue in DX beta?

Here is a snippet of code I put together to show the flow I do.

```
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    const rp = require('request-promise');

    let options = {
      issuer: clientId,
      audience: audience,
      expiresIn: 20000,
      algorithm: 'RS256'
    };

    let token = jwt.sign({prn: userName}, privateKey, options);

    const accessToken = await rp(
    {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
        form: {
            'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
            'assertion': token
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        return reply.access_token;
    });

    let loginUrl = "https://CS65.salesforce.com";
    const hubConn = new jsforce.Connection(
        {
            instanceUrl: loginUrl,
            accessToken: accessToken,
            version: "40.0"
        }
    );

    const scratchOrgInfo = hubConn.sobject('scratchOrgInfo');
    await scratchOrgInfo.describe();

    // create scratch org
    console.log('Creating scratch org....');
    const {id, success, errors} = await scratchOrgInfo.create({
        Country: 'US',
        Edition: 'Developer',
        OrgName: 'testorg',
        AdminEmail: AdminEmail,
        ConnectedAppConsumerKey: clientId,
        ConnectedAppCallbackUrl: redirectUrl,
    });
    if (!success) {
        console.error(errors);
        throw new Error('Error occurred while creating scratch org');
    }

    const orgInfo = await scratchOrgInfo.retrieve(id);

    // establish connection with scratch org
    const loginUrl = `https://${orgInfo.SignupInstance}.salesforce.com`;
    const scratchOrgConn = new jsforce.Connection(
        {
            instanceUrl: loginUrl,
            accessToken: accessToken,
            version: "40.0"
        }
    );
    const scratchOrgIdentity = await scratchOrgConn.identity() //Fails here on calling https://{instanceUrl}.salesforce.com/services/data/v40.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a sample code that works for me. I see that you are passing token information as `formdata` instead of body. and have you checked your response for `token`? does it return a valid value or is it blank?

```
var rsa_payload = {
  "sub":account_id,
  "aud":reqUrl
}

var rsa_options = {
  header:{
    "alg":"RS256",
    "typ":"JWT"
   },
   expiresIn: '1h'
}

 // Sign the JWT payload
var assertion = jwt.sign(
  rsa_payload,
  private_key,
  rsa_options
);

var options = {
  url: reqUrl,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'accept': 'application/json'
  },
  body:`grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=${encodeURIComponent(assertion)}`
}

// Make the OAuth call to generate a token
request.post(options, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(response)
})
```